# Laravel 5 not getting any error logs

Tags: php, linux, apache, laravel, vps

I installed Laravel 5 on a new VPS, I was running everything fine but I noticed I wasn't getting any Laravel errors the system would only fire a server 500 error at me which is no help when debugging my code.

When I looked in the laravel `storage/log` it was empty which was strange because I had set the correct file permissions of `777`.

So how do I get laravel logs? Why aren't they being written to my `storage/log` file.

Comment: if any errors isn't writing in project error.log,then check first your server error log,it will told you where is the problem.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin StackOverflow both permits and *encourages* users to answer their own questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 11):

If you've set your file permissions correctly on the `/storage` file directory and you're running on a VPS not shared hosting you might want to check your apache log, inside `var/log/apache2/error.log`

Here you might just see a line that read something along the lines of `/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Well this is strange because you have the correct file permissions...

Let's start by SSH'ing into your VPS head to the directory where laravel is installed normally `cd /var/www/html`

In here if you run `ls -l` You should get some results similar to this image below:
[image]

Notice how we've been accessing the site as the root user, this is our problem and we can confirm this by running `ps aux | grep apache2`

[image]

You can see here apache2 is running as the user www-data, which is normal for apache. Which means when our laravel installation trys to move files either using `->move()` or just trying to write the log file it fails as the www-data user doesn't have permission. So you can change to this `www-data` user by running: `chown -R www-data:www-data *` (shorthand for same user/group `chown -R www-data. *`)

Now if you run `ls -l` in your `www/html` directory you should see root user changed to www-data:

[image]

This means were now editing the files as the www-data user which has permission, so any changes you make via SFTP should reflect this user change. Fixed!

*Edit - This is the first time I answered my own question hopefully it's okay.*

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question.